# Separating 3-d array into 2-d arrays along the respective columns

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

```
temp1 = tempObj[0][0]
temp2 = tempObj[0][1]
if len(tempObj) > 1:
    for i in range(1, len(tempObj)):
    temp1 = np.vstack((temp1, tempObj[i][0]))
    temp2 = np.vstack((temp2, tempObj[i][1]))
```

The code is in Python. In the above code, I am trying to separate the numpy 3-d array (tempObj) into two 2-d arrays (temp1 & temp2) so that the respective columns are merged.
Is there a better or simpler way to do this?

Comment: `tempObj[:,0]` and `tempObj[:,1]`?

Comment: @Divakar : It doesn't work for 3-d array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `tempObj[:, 0, :]` and `tempObj[:, 1, :]`. here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
tempObj = np.array([
    [
        [1,5], [2,7], [3,8], [4,4],
        [6, 5], [4, 7], [13, 8], [9, 4]
    ],

    [
        [21,25], [22,72], [32,82], [34,43],
        [64, 54], [44, 74], [1443, 48], [94, 44]
    ],
    [
        [211, 215], [212, 712], [312, 812], [314, 413],
        [614, 514], [414, 714], [11443, 148], [194, 414]
    ]

])

# Your code:
############################################
temp1 = tempObj[0][0]
temp2 = tempObj[0][1]
if len(tempObj) > 1:
    for i in range(1, len(tempObj)):
        temp1 = np.vstack((temp1, tempObj[i][0]))
        temp2 = np.vstack((temp2, tempObj[i][1]))
print(temp1)
print(temp2)

# my suggestion
############################################
print(tempObj[:, 0, :])
print(tempObj[:, 1, :])
```

You need to make sure that the type of `tempObj` (or any part of it) is `numpy.ndarray` and not `list`. You can do it by typing `print(type(tempObj))`. The following example is what I suspect that is your code that gives an error of `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple`:

```
tempObj = [
    np.array([
        [1,5], [2,7], [3,8], [4,4],
        [6, 5], [4, 7], [13, 8], [9, 4]
    ]),
    np.array([
        [21,25], [22,72], [32,82], [34,43],
        [64, 54], [44, 74], [1443, 48], [94, 44]
    ]),
    np.array([
        [211, 215], [212, 712], [312, 812], [314, 413],
        [614, 514], [414, 714], [11443, 148], [194, 414]
    ])
]
```

Comment: The following error comes up:

`TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple`

Comment: so you can change it to `numpy.ndarray` by typing `tempObj = np.array(tempObj)` and then use `tempObj[:, 0, :]` etc.

Comment: The follwing error comes:
`tempObj = np.array(tempObj)`

`ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4) into shape (1)`

I even tried this, but the same error comes up:
`temp1 = np.array(tempObj)[:, 0, :]`

`ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4) into shape (1)`

Comment: `tempObj = [[array([[0.10637, -0.1495, -0.0374, -0.2185],
       [ 0.1551, -0.0893,  0.036,  0.0282],
       [ 0.2061,  0.5072,  0.3971,  0.3163],
       [-0.1448,  0.2442,  0.0603,  0.0389],
       [-1.0165,  1.0355 ,  0.0088,  0.0101]]),
array([[ 0.98874854,  0.97787452,  0.99859974,  0.95337157],
       [ 0.97623035,  0.99196171,  0.99863394,  0.99919989],
       [ 0.95837367,  0.77314455,  0.85411506,  0.90477692],
       [ 0.97922599,  0.9420922 ,  0.99636324,  0.99848106],
       [ 0.35578364,  0.34216564,  0.99992133,  0.99989703]])]]`

Comment: ok, now I understand. use `tempObj = np.array(tempObj[0])` and then `tempObj[0, :, :]` and `tempObj[1, :, :]`